# phpmyadmin is working fine but I can't find config.inc.php file?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is weird

I have phpmyadmin 4.2.5 installed on my Windows 7 machine, it currently is working fine and located in localhost/phpmyadmin

I can view, edit, create databases, tables, etc.

Now I wanted to change some settings and so I looked for the config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory but it's not there?

I have a config.sample.inc.php but obviously it's just a sample

I did a search and the only config.inc.php file is in the /setup/frames/ folder which is clearly not the main config file.

So where is it? I installed phpmyadmin last month and I think I just copied it to my htdocs folder, nothing special, but I can't remember if I did something different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***The `config.inc.php` file is not required, and only needed for custom configurations***

phpmyadmin will first refer to `./libraries/config.default.php` to retrieve the default values.

If for some reason you need to modify the default values, and the `./config.inc.php` file doesn't exist, you will need to create one as per the [Installation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file) documentation.

You will also need to [configure pmadb](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) for some of phpmyadmin's special features such as bookmarks.

Comment: It doesn't need the file, in which case the defaults are used. It's only needed for custom configurations. You can also copy the sample config and use it.

Comment: @EternalHour, can you describe the exact file path of config.default.php?

Answer (score 7):

rename config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php and edit whatever you want in it.

Answer (score 4):

if by mistake you have changed the password of your default user('root') and now phpmyadmin is not even allowing you to open it than:

1. go to ***config.inc.php*** file
2. change your ***$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '  '***

put ur password in **'  '** that u changed.

**C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14** for **config.inc.php**

Answer (score 3):

Open up `[web_root]/libraries/Config.class.php` add these lines to the beginning of the method `load`:

```
      var_dump( $this->default_source);
      var_dump( CONFIG_FILE);
      die;
```

Open phpmyadmin. This is the order of config files loaded, they make a variable `$cfg` which is the config of PMA, for me the output was:

```
'[mywebroot]./libraries/config.default.php'
'/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php'
```

Make sure the last file, which is for local changes, exist and have correct permissions. Then get rid of the added lines.

**More info**

PMA loads it's global configuration in the file `libraries/common.inc.php:306`.

```
$GLOBALS['PMA_Config'] = new PMA_Config(CONFIG_FILE);
```

The global is an instance of `PMA_Config` whose constructor calls the `load`method. In load method, the parameter passed to the constructor, `CONFIG_FILE` is used to load the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Initially this file is not present. After Restart XAMPP/WAMP, it is created.

Go to path ***c:\xamp\phpmyadmin***.In that folder ***config.inc.php*** file would be present.