# config.inc.php missing in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to contribute to phpMyAdmin. I cloned the code from Github but it has config.sample.inc.php and the file config.inc.php is missing. I guess there is some way to generate it from setup but I am not getting how? How can I generate that file automatically? Have I to do it manually? How can I use setup/index.php?

My question is different from: [phpmyadmin is working fine but I can't find config.inc.php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007764/phpmyadmin-is-working-fine-but-i-cant-find-config-inc-php-file)
as it does not ask how to generate that file.
Thanks for help :)

The generated file after I used setup script is this:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: user in <b>C:\xampp\phpmyadmin\libraries\Console.php</b> on line <b>129</b><br />
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /><style id="cfs-style">html{display: none;}</style><link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css?v=4.8.0-dev" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css?v=4.8.0-dev" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css?v=4.8.0-dev" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=2979123735ltr" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./themes/pmahomme/css/printview.css?v=4.8.0-dev" media="print" id="printcss"/><title>phpMyAdmin</title><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.min.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=sprintf.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=ajax.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=keyhandler.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-ui.min.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.cookie.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js&amp;v=4.8.0-dev"></script><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.debounce-1.0.5.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=menu-resizer.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=cross_framing_protection.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=rte.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=tracekit/tracekit.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=error_report.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=config.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=doclinks.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=functions.js&amp;v=4.8.0-dev"></script><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=navigation.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=indexes.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=common.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=page_settings.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=shortcuts_handler.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/lib/codemirror.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/mode/sql/sql.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/hint/sql-hint.js&amp;v=4.8.0-dev"></script><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/lint/sql-lint.js&amp;scripts%5B%5D=console.js&amp;v=4.8.0-dev"></script><script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='js/whitelist.php?lang=en&amp;db=&v=4.8.0-dev'></script><script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='js/messages.php?lang=en&amp;db=&v=4.8.0-dev'></script><script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='js/get_image.js.php?theme=pmahomme&v=4.8.0-dev'></script><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
PMA_commonParams.setAll({common_query:"",opendb_url:"db_structure.php",collation_connection:"utf8mb4_general_ci",lang:"en",server:"0",table:"",db:"",token:"06461bce34a3afc4ea2bb89c1386e917",text_dir:"ltr",show_databases_navigation_as_tree:"1",pma_text_default_tab:"Browse",pma_text_left_default_tab:"Structure",pma_text_left_default_tab2:"",LimitChars:"50",pftext:"",confirm:"1",LoginCookieValidity:"1440",session_gc_maxlifetime:"1440",logged_in:"",PMA_VERSION:"4.8.0-dev"});
ConsoleEnterExecutes=false
AJAX.scriptHandler.add("jquery/jquery.min.js",0).add("jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js",0).add("whitelist.php?lang=en&amp;db=",1).add("sprintf.js",1).add("ajax.js",0).add("keyhandler.js",1).add("jquery/jquery-ui.min.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.cookie.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js",0).add("jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.debounce-1.0.5.js",0).add("menu-resizer.js",1).add("cross_framing_protection.js",0).add("rte.js",1).add("tracekit/tracekit.js",1).add("error_report.js",1).add("messages.php?lang=en&amp;db=",0).add("get_image.js.php?theme=pmahomme",0).add("config.js",1).add("doclinks.js",1).add("functions.js",1).add("navigation.js",1).add("indexes.js",1).add("common.js",1).add("page_settings.js",1).add("shortcuts_handler.js",1).add("codemirror/lib/codemirror.js",0).add("codemirror/mode/sql/sql.js",0).add("codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.js",0).add("codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js",0).add("codemirror/addon/hint/sql-hint.js",0).add("codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js",0).add("codemirror/addon/lint/sql-lint.js",0).add("console.js",1);
$(function() {AJAX.fireOnload("whitelist.php?lang=en&amp;db=");AJAX.fireOnload("sprintf.js");AJAX.fireOnload("keyhandler.js");AJAX.fireOnload("menu-resizer.js");AJAX.fireOnload("rte.js");AJAX.fireOnload("tracekit/tracekit.js");AJAX.fireOnload("error_report.js");AJAX.fireOnload("config.js");AJAX.fireOnload("doclinks.js");AJAX.fireOnload("functions.js");AJAX.fireOnload("navigation.js");AJAX.fireOnload("indexes.js");AJAX.fireOnload("common.js");AJAX.fireOnload("page_settings.js");AJAX.fireOnload("shortcuts_handler.js");AJAX.fireOnload("console.js");});
// ]]></script><noscript><style>html{display:block}</style></noscript></head><body><noscript><div class="error"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="" alt="" class="icon ic_s_error" /> Javascript must be enabled past this point!</div></noscript><div id="pma_console_container">
<div id="pma_console">
    <!-- Console toolbar -->
    <div class="toolbar collapsed">
        <div class="switch_button console_switch">
        <img src="themes/dot.gif" title="SQL Query Console" alt="SQL Query Console" class="icon ic_console" />            <span> Console </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button clear">
                    <span> Clear </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button history">
                    <span> History </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button options">
                    <span> Options </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button bookmarks">
                    <span> Bookmarks </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button debug hide">
                    <span> Debug SQL </span>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Toolbar end -->
    <!-- Console messages -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="console_message_container">
            <div class="message welcome">
                <span id="instructions-0">
                    Press Ctrl+Enter to execute query                    </span>
                <span class="hide" id="instructions-1">
                    Press Enter to execute query                    </span>
            </div>
                        </div> <!-- console_message_container -->
        <div class="query_input">
            <span class="console_query_input"></span>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- message end -->
    <!-- Drak the console with other cards over it -->
    <div class="mid_layer"></div>
    <!-- Debug SQL card -->
    <div class="card" id="debug_console">
        <div class="toolbar ">
        <div class="button order order_asc">
                    <span> ascending </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button order order_desc">
                    <span> descending </span>
    </div>
        <div class="text">
                    <span> Order: </span>
    </div>
        <div class="switch_button">
                    <span> Debug SQL </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button order_by sort_count">
                    <span> Count </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button order_by sort_exec">
                    <span> Execution order </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button order_by sort_time">
                    <span> Time taken </span>
    </div>
        <div class="text">
                    <span> Order by: </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button group_queries">
                    <span> Group queries </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button ungroup_queries">
                    <span> Ungroup queries </span>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="content debug">
            <div class="message welcome"></div>
            <div class="debugLog"></div>
        </div> <!-- Content -->
        <div class="templates">
            <div class="debug_query action_content">
        <span class="action collapse">
        Collapse                    </span>
        <span class="action expand">
        Expand                    </span>
        <span class="action dbg_show_trace">
        Show trace                    </span>
        <span class="action dbg_hide_trace">
        Hide trace                    </span>
        <span class="text count hide">
        Count                            : <span>  </span>
                </span>
        <span class="text time">
        Time taken                            : <span>  </span>
                </span>
</div>
        </div> <!-- Template -->
    </div> <!-- Debug SQL card -->
            <!-- Options card: -->
    <div class="card" id="pma_console_options">
        <div class="toolbar ">
        <div class="switch_button">
                    <span> Options </span>
    </div>
        <div class="button default">
                    <span> Set default </span>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="content">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="always_expand">Always expand query messages                </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="start_history">Show query history at start                </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="current_query">Show current browsing query                </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="enter_executes">
                    Execute queries on Enter and insert new line with Shift + Enter. To make this permanent, view settings.                </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="dark_theme">Switch to dark theme                </label>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Options card -->
    <div class="templates">
        <!-- Templates for console message actions -->
        <div class="query_actions">
        <span class="action collapse">
        Collapse                    </span>
        <span class="action expand">
        Expand                    </span>
        <span class="action requery">
        Requery                    </span>
        <span class="action edit">
        Edit                    </span>
        <span class="action explain">
        Explain                    </span>
        <span class="action profiling">
        Profiling                    </span>
        <span class="action bookmark">
        Bookmark                    </span>
        <span class="text failed">
        Query failed                    </span>
        <span class="text targetdb">
        Database                            : <span>  </span>
                </span>
        <span class="text query_time">
        Queried time                            : <span>  </span>
                </span>
</div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- #console end -->
</div> <!-- #console_container end -->
<div id="page_content"><?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.8.0-dev setup script
 * Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 12:46:21 +0000
 */
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?></div><div id="selflink" class="print_ignore"><a href="config.php?db=&amp;table=&amp;server=0&amp;target=" title="Open new phpMyAdmin window" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Open new phpMyAdmin window" alt="Open new phpMyAdmin window" class="icon ic_window-new" /></a></div><div class="clearfloat" id="pma_errors"></div><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var debugSQLInfo = 'null';
AJAX.scriptHandler;
$(function() {});
// ]]></script></body></html>
```

I Dont get why There is html code in this file? Did I make some mistake?

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007764/phpmyadmin-is-working-fine-but-i-cant-find-config-inc-php-file

Comment: That question does not ask how to create one. So mine is a bit different. Anyways atleast I got to know that it is not necessary to have that file. Thanks

Comment: just copy your config.sample.inc.php, name it config.inc.php and edit the new file with your settings. This file is needed just for configuration but is not strictly needed to run phpmyadmin

Comment: Have you tried following the [installation steps in the manual](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file)…?

Comment: I tried those steps @deceze . but the generated file even had html and css code in it apart from a few actual php config options. I didnt get the use of the html code in that file.

Comment: What does that mean? The section in the manual I link to above says to copy the sample config file and create a `config.inc.php` with your favourite text editor. At what point does that file start to include HTML…?!

Comment: @KashyapKotak that file is just a set of configuration options. Is not supposed to be accessible from the browser. Where the HTML is coming from? The file is just pure PHP

Comment: That page also has a section named using setup script to automatically generate the file. It's just below manually creating. I tried that. @deceze.

Comment: And What. *Exactly.* Happened. When you tried that…?

Comment: I was surprised to see that. After I clicked the download button, a file named config.inc.php was downloaded. When I opened it, I saw many html tags and php was at the end of the file. Is there any way I can share that file here? Anyways I am creating it manually. Thanks

Comment: I have clearly mentioned what I am asking for. How to generate it automatically? Is manual only option? and how to use setup? Then how is it unclear?

Comment: If that is indeed what the setup script produces, it looks like a bug and you should file a bug with the phpmyadmin guys.