# Where do I find config.inc.php on myphpadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to drop a database from PHPmyadmin but the option is not enabled. I googled and it says you have to change some values on config.inc.php.
I just can't find the config.inc.php file. I'm supposed to login through a program or something?

Comment: In windows, you can find the file `xampp\phpMyAdmin`

Comment: For Linux you can do this `$ whereis phpMyAdmin`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin is working fine but I can't find config.inc.php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007764/phpmyadmin-is-working-fine-but-i-cant-find-config-inc-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your "SERVER" if you're using xampp like me then, just open the program and on the top right you will fing config button with a small icon, click it and BOOM there you are, Hope it helps .